# Mod_Rewrite: wildcard to subdomain loading to 404?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Typically with shared hosting, there's a main (pirmary) domain and addon domains which can be accessed via the main domain like: addon.main.com. Here's a solution from a Hostgator help page, 
but it requires a specific subname (for the addon):

```
#Prevent subdomain name loading.
#This goes in htaccess for the primary domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subname\.primary\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subname\.primary\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.addon\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

I have modified the third line of code to give a 404, and it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subname\.primary\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subname\.primary\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404]
```

But how can I modify the first line such that if a user typed *any* string placed as the subname (IE: abcdefg.primary.com) it would give the 404?
I've tried this but no luck:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.primary\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.subname\.primary\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404]
```

What would be the proper wildcard to use?  Thanks.

Comment: So you want the user to be redirected to 404 pages if they try to access `(www.)?something.primary.com`?

Comment: Yes, any string.  I figured if I had some type of wildcard in that first line, but (.*) isn't working.  What might?